# How to do nested query between contact and opportunity?

Tags: soql, query

I want to make query like this:

```
List<Contact> conList = [SELECT id, name FROM Contact WHERE id IN: 
                        [SELECT contactId FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won']];
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

This works:

```
List<Contact> conList = [SELECT id, name FROM Contact WHERE id =: 
                        [SELECT contactId FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won'].contactId];
```

But I cannot use `IN` with outer query condition, and if the inner query returns more than one result it throws an error.

I know I can split the queries into two, one for `opportunity`, use a lopp to store the `contactId` in a `set` and use this `set` in the `contact` query. But was wondering if it possible with a nested query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the right idea just the wrong syntax for the semi-join (not technically an inner query).  Try this:

```
List<Contact> conList = [
     SELECT id, name 
     FROM Contact
     WHERE id IN (SELECT contactId FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won')
];
```